# Constrain available date values in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

Is it possible to constrain the calender prompt? I want that the users only can select current and the last year. But not more. Now they can select all years infinite.

[image: Calender]

Comment: You cannot change calendar control functionality. Think that the user can write the date in the textbox. If you want to apply limits you have to do it in the query and having a message for the user running the report that the selected date is not valid.

Comment: I can make it happen, that if the user select 2022 than I can create a message, that the data is not available? How?

Comment: Add a textbox. When the user runs the report the textbox will display the error message. Filter your dataset to return no data in this case

Comment: I'd use a calendar table. Then you can filter it for the dates you need. You'll need to update the available values of the date parameters.

Comment: This will display a dropdown with dates instead of a calendar

Comment: calender is more user friendly

Comment: Why display an error message? If there's no data in the future, then the report will be blank. Just add the date (range) to a subtitle/subheader line so the user sees it on the report.